# AJAX - Certificado expirado

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, certificado-ssl

hay alguna forma de que pueda hacer una peticion POST a una URL con certificado expirado? Esto si con AJAX Jquery.
El siguiente codigo es simple para hacer solicitudes

```
var param = parametros;
url = url_api;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: param,
}).done(function(data){
   //--
})
```

El error que me sale en el AJAX en el apartado de seguridad es:
SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE
Y no me muestra la respuesta

Comment: Puedes Mostar el código que ya tienes hecho?

Comment: Voy a ponerlo pero es simple, investigue y no encontre algo para que me permita hacer las solicitudes con normalidad

Comment: Certificado expirado?, ummmm realmente para hacer una peticion POST o peticion GET el certificado es lo de menos, tu siempre puedes hacer una peticion POST o peticion GET a un sitio, solo necesitas que el sitio no este caido obviamente, ya otra cosa diferente seria que la pagina rechazara tu peticion o no la este recibiendo.

Comment: Lo digo porque no me muestra nada y me sale este error en el apartado de seguridad @Riven SEC_ERROR_EXPIRED_CERTIFICATE

Comment: ¿Verificaste que la fecha de tu sistema sea la correcta? Sólo por descartar posibles fallas.

Comment: Si, solo quiero saber que debo hacer para que admita certificados expirados